# Getting from Milan Linate to Bergamo

Tags: airports, milan, bergamo

What is the fastest way to get from Linate airport to Bergamo centre? A quick Google search showed me GoOpti transfer company but I have never heard about them. Would anybody recommend them?

Comment: You should rent a car.